# Notation of integrals

Tags: soft-question, notation, integration

Hi I am relatively new to quantum mechanics. I encountered a certain use of notation which I am curious about, I will provide the context and question now:

We have the basis $\{ | \vec{r} \rangle \} $ which are eigenkets to the position operator $\hat{\vec{R}}$:

The completeness condition is given as 
$$\int d^3r  | \vec{r} \rangle \langle \vec{r} | = \hat{I} .$$
I can see that this is in analogy with the finite dimensional case i.e. $\sum_n | e_n \rangle \langle e_n | = 1 $.

Question: What exactly does this integral mean (it doesn't seem clear since the integrand seems to be outside the integral), is this just a notational convention or does is imply something different? Since I know that for any ket $\phi \rangle$ we can write $$\int d^3r  | \vec{r} \rangle \langle \vec{r} |\phi \rangle = | \phi \rangle$$ so again it seems that $| \vec{r} \rangle \langle \vec{r} |$ is something outside the integrand, since any ket can be attached to form $\langle \vec{r} |\phi \rangle$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200378/2451

Comment: I assume you are not concerned that $d^{3}r$ is to the left of the integrand, correct?  That is perfectly okay and somewhat a matter of preference for different people.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks for your response. I assume that this is just a convention. But I am mainly interested in exactly what this integral means. It is clearly given as an operator (the identity operator $\hat I$). But this is because any bra $| \phi \rangle$ can move into the integrand to give $\int d^3r | \vec{r} \rangle \langle \vec{r} | \phi \rangle $, is this allowed for the following reason: Is this simply because $r$ is constant for any particular $|\phi \rangle$, hence $|\phi \rangle$ can move into the integrand?

Comment: I think the $\langle A \mid B \rangle$ is just a [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation) for the inner product.  Whereas the expression $\mid A \rangle \langle B \mid$ is similar to the outer product.  However, the notation is used for operators and abstract states, not just vector spaces.  It's been over 10 years since my last quantum class so I am a bit rusty...

Answer (score 3):

The notations $\int f(r)\, dr$  and  $\int dr\,f(r)$ are equivalent. The latter is convenient if you have nested integrals, e.g. 
$$\int_0^\infty dr\int_0^\pi d\theta\,f(r,\theta),$$
so that you can see which integration limit belongs to which integration variable.

The notation $d^3r$ is a shorthand for "integrate over 3D space", for example $dx\,dy\,dz$ if $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$. Depending on the symmetry of the problem, it might be more convenient to use cylindrical coordinates $(z,r,\theta)$, in which case $d^3r=r\,dr\,dz\,d\theta$.

***Update after comment*** The integrand $f(r)$ can be a scalar or a vector; the result of the integral will likewise be a scalar or a vector. A ket $|\phi\rangle$ is also a kind of vector, although it is with an unspecified set of basis vectors. To get a more traditional vector as a list of numbers $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, you need to build brackets, such that $a_i=\langle e_i|\phi\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for response. For clarity would I be right in stating that if we explicitly define $|\vec{r} \rangle$ and $|\phi \rangle$ then we would integrate as we would any vector valued function, which is component-wise?